# Google Plus Login App without getting access to the people in the circles?

Tags: api, google-api, google-plus

I am programming a login-script with the Google Plus Platform.
Is there a possibility to only get the User-ID but not the people in the circles from the person and no access to app-activities? My APP really only needs the ID of the User.

[image: I don't need this, only the ID]

[image: I don't need this, only the ID]

Comment: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me works but only on the Google OAuth 2.0 Playground.

Not for my script :/

Comment: Maybe you should change your screenshots so that they are in English. Not everyone around here speaks German ;-)

Comment: @AlexanderVogt : They are just symbolically. :P
But you can test here, so you will see: http://phip1611.de/gplogin/
remove connection manually at https://plus.google.com/apps

Comment: What API calls are you making that plus.me fails on? plus.me will allow people.get calls, which will return the Google id of the user, as will the ID token that is returned from authentication.

Comment: https://plus.google.com/u/0/115588584039634031388/posts/3VbzvSKc6W9
Ian Barber said that they r trying to fix that.